# I have created a custom module for backed to add menu and submenu but it shows me Error?

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml, template

I have created a custom module for back end Menu and sub menu but it shows me an error.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 
'Admin_CreateMenuBackend::commision.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Backend' block's name: 
'content_schedule_block1'
```

My createmenubackend_create_index.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
   <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Admin_CreateMenuBackend::helloworld.phtml"/>
   </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```

routes.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
<route id="createmenubackend" frontName="createmenubackend">
<module name="Admin_CreateMenuBackend" before="Magento_Backend"/>
</route>
</router>
</config>
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: is that Magento 1.x.x or 2.x?

Comment: Magento 2 @AlanZavagli

Comment: Do you have a `commision.phtml` file created in templates?

Comment: no i have created helloworld.phtml with path /app/code/Admin/CreateMenuBackend/view/adminhtml/templates/helloworld.pthml @joeybab3

Comment: Changed my filename as you can see my createmenubackend_create_index.xml file @joeybab3

Comment: Well the error message you posted seems to be looking for a file called `commision.phtml`. Is there somewhere that you have attempted to use this filename?

Comment: yes firstly it would be commision.phtml then i have changed it to helloworld.pthml @joeybab3

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the routes.xml adding the before="Magento_Backend" like:

```
<router id="admin">
   <route id="vendor_module" frontName="vendor_module">
      <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend"/>
   </route>
</router>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.Updated before="Magento_Backend" in my routes.xml but still getting the same error.
I have updated that in my question also plz check if i am missing something @Alan