# How to save Checkout field data Guest User in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, error, api, guest-checkout

I have created a module in which created some fields and save data in Magneto 2 but there is some issue regarding to save that custom data for guest user.

my file app/code/Reg/Checkout/Api/Data/SimpleNoteInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Reg\Checkout\Api\Data;
/**
 * Interface SimpleNoteInterface
 */
interface SimpleNoteInterface
{
/**
 * Get Simple Note
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSimpleNote();
/**
 * Set Simple Note
 *
 * @param string $simpleNote
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setSimpleNote($simpleNote);
}
```

my app/code/Reg/Checkout/Api/SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Reg\Checkout\Api;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

/**
 * Interface SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface
 *
 * @category Api/Interface
 * @package  Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Api
 */
interface SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface
{
/**
 * Save checkout custom fields
 *
 * @param string                                                   $cartId       Guest Cart id
 * @param \Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Api\Data\CustomFieldsInterface $customFields Custom fields
 *
 * @return \Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Api\Data\CustomFieldsInterface
 */
public function saveCustomFields(
    string $cartId,
    \Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleNoteInterface $simpleNote
): SimpleNoteInterface;
}
```

my app/code/Reg/Checkout/Model/SimpleNoteGuestManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace Reg\Checkout\Model;

use Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleNoteInterface;
use Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface;
use Reg\Checkout\Setup\SchemaInformation;
use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class SimpleNoteManagement
 */
class SimpleNoteGuestManagement implements 
SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface
{
/**
 * Quote repository.
 *
 * @var CartRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $quoteRepository;
protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;

/**
 * @var CustomFieldsRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $customFieldsRepository;

/**
 * SimpleNoteManagement constructor.
 *
 * @param CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
 */
public function __construct(
    CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
    uoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory,
    CustomFieldsRepositoryInterface $customFieldsRepository
)
{
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    $this->quoteIdMaskFactory     = $quoteIdMaskFactory;
    $this->customFieldsRepository = $customFieldsRepository;
}

/**
 * Save simple note number in the quote
 *
 * @param int $cartId
 * @param SimpleNoteInterface $simpleNote
 *
 * @return null|string
 *
 * @throws CouldNotSaveException
 * @throws NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function saveSimpleNote(
    string $cartId,
    SimpleNoteInterface $simpleNote
): SimpleNoteInterface {
    $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
    return $this->customFieldsRepository->saveSimpleNote((int)$quoteIdMask->getQuoteId(), $simpleNote);
}
}
```

my app/code/Reg/Checkout/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleNoteInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\Data\SimpleNote" />
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleVehicleInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\Data\SimpleAge" />
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleRegisteredInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\Data\SimpleKeeper" />
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteManagementInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\SimpleNoteManagement" />
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\SimpleNoteGuestManagement" />
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\VehicleAgeManagementInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\VehicleAgeManagement" />
<preference for="Reg\Checkout\Api\RegisterKeeperManagementInterface" type="Reg\Checkout\Model\RegisteredKeeperManagement" />
<virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid" type="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Grid">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="simple_note" xsi:type="string">sales_order.simple_note</item>
            <item name="vehicle_age" xsi:type="string">sales_order.vehicle_age</item>
            <item name="registered_keeper" xsi:type="string">sales_order.registered_keeper</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
</config>
```

my app/code/Reg/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/save-order-simple-note.js

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'mage/url'
],
function ($, quote, urlBuilder, customer, errorProcessor, urlFormatter) {
'use strict';

return {
    /**
     * Save SimpleNote ibn the quote
     *
     * @param simpleNote
     */
    save: function (simpleNote) {
        if (simpleNote) {
            var quoteId = quote.getQuoteId();
            var url;
            url = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/set-simple-note', {cartId: quoteId});

            var payload = {
                cartId: quoteId,
                simpleNote: {
                    simpleNote: simpleNote
                }
            };

            if (!payload.simpleNote.simpleNote) {

                return true;
            }

            var result = true;

            $.ajax({
                url: urlFormatter.build(url),
                data: JSON.stringify(payload),
                global: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: 'PUT',
                async: false
            }).done(
                function (response) {
                    result = true;
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    result = false;
                    errorProcessor.process(response);
                }
            );

            return result;
        }
    }
};
});
```

It gives me error

On setup:di:compile i'm getting PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Reg\Checkout\Model\SimpleNoteGuestManagement::saveSimpleNote(string $cartId, Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleNoteInterface $simpleNote): Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleNoteInterface must be compatible with Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface::saveSimpleNote(string $cartId, Reg\Checkout\Api\Data\SimpleNoteInterface $simpleNote): Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteInterface in /var/www/html/reg-dealers/app/code/Reg/Checkout/Model/SimpleNoteGuestManagement.php on line 15

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You either remove the return type `CustomFieldsInterface` from the method `Reg\Checkout\Model\SimpleNoteGuestManagement::saveSimpleNote` or you add it to the interface method `Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface::saveSimpleNote`.

Comment: I have updated my file Reg\Checkout\Api\SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface::saveSimpleNote  will you please check if i done it correctly or not actually i am new to this.@Marius

Comment: it looks ok now. clear the cache and run setup:di:compile again

Comment: Updated my app/code/Reg/Checkout/Api/SimpleNoteGuestManagementInterface.php file.

Comment: Updated my error in question which comes on setup:di:compile @Marius please help.

Comment: will you please help me with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319655/i-have-created-a-custom-module-for-backed-to-add-menu-and-submenu-but-it-shows-m/319707#319707 this question @Marius

Comment: It gives me this error <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function saveSimpleNote() on null in /var/www/html/reg-dealers/app/code/Reg/Checkout/Model/SimpleNoteGuestManagement.php:81 @Marius