# Custom Controller goes to 404 in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, controllers, 404, routing

I have created a custom controller and die on controller execute page but it goes to 404 ?

COntroller file ( path : app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/helloworld.php )

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

My helloworld_index_index.xml ( path : app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/froentend/layout/helloworld_index_hello.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Index" name="helloworld_index_testcron" template="Mageplaza_HelloWorld::index.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

my rotes.xml ( path : app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/froentend/routes.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
        <module name="Mageplaza_HelloWorld" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

**I have hit http://127.0.0.1/projectname/helloworld/index/index but it goes to 404** Any help is appriciated

Comment: Please add your file path too.

Comment: Updated my file path please check @PratikOza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong file path added in module. Update from **froentend** to **frontend**.

Also update controller path

**From:**

> app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/helloworld.php

**To:**

> app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php

For more detail, please refer to the [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for response will you please look into this questin https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319739/how-to-save-checkout-field-data-guest-user-in-magento-2 @Pratik